# Set a specific workspace on an external monitor

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, xrandr, wayland, mutter

My laptop is connected to an external monitor and I am using an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have several workspaces and I would like to clone one of the workspace on the external monitor.

To specify the question, assume I have 3 workspaces called A, B and C. I would like to clone workspace A on the external monitor with the possibility to switch between the different workspaces on the main screen, still displaying workspace A on the external monitor.

How to proceed ? Even a command-line solution would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a useful functionality. I hope someone finds a solution to this requirement.

Comment: That would be amazing. Haver you ever found a solution?

Comment: No, I don't have a solution, but I'm still interested in an answer.