# Pin workspace to external monitor/projector?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, workspaces

Is there any way to pin a workspace to a projector on Ubuntu 22.04. I need this feature because I try to teach a programming class, where I complete the code (on Jupyter notebook) during the class. It would be useful to have a duplication of a specific workspace where I code, while I can do other stuff on the rest of the workspaces.

Before anyone complains, this is a duplicate of [Set a specific workspace on an external monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191595/set-a-specific-workspace-on-an-external-monitor) (an unanswered question).